# Maya and Cuda 11 type redeclaration error

Tags: c++, cuda, namespaces, maya, maya-api

Bit of a newb here with trying to link cuda with other apps. I’m trying to compile a Maya plugin and link cuda 11 in the plugin. I’m getting the same error that’s been listed a number of times, however the fixes don’t seem to work any longer. It’s a straight forward plugin.

I have a displace.cuh file that is included in both the .cu file and the .cpp file for my plugin.

```
#include “cuda.h”
#include “cuda_runtime.h”
void cu_displace();
int cuda_displace();
```

and a displace.cu

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include “dlCudaDisplace.h”
__global __ void displace() {
int x = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
int offset = x * blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
printf(“running cuda code\n”);
}
int cuda_displace() {
dim3 blocks(DIM/16,DIM/16);
dim3 threads(16,16);
//
displace<<<blocks, threads>>>();
return 0;
}
```

I get these errors for all the various types that are the same as in Cuda.

```
C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2021\include\maya/MTypes.h(219): note: see declaration of ‘double4’
```

However, trying this

```
namespace cuda {
#include “cuda.h”
#include “cuda_runtime.h”
}
```

Gives these errors.

```
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.0\include\cuda_runtime.h(310): error C2039: ‘cudaEventCreateWithFlags’: is no
t a member of ‘global namespace'' C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.0\include\cuda_runtime.h(376): error C2039: 'cudaHostAlloc': is not a member of 'global namespace’’
```

I’m using CMake to build the plugin, with these cuda variables

```
find_package(Maya REQUIRED)
find_package(CUDA REQUIRED)
enable_language(CUDA)
set(CMAKE_CUDA_FLAGS "{CMAKE_CUDA_FLAGS} -gencode arch=compute_50,code=sm_50 -lcuda -lcudart") include_directories({MAYA_INCLUDE_DIR})
link_directories({MAYA_LIBRARY_DIR}) add_library({PROJECT_NAME} SHARED {SOURCE_FILES}) target_link_libraries({PROJECT_NAME} ${MAYA_LIBRARIES})
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You don't need and shouldn't have the cuda includes in displace.cuh

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this working now.  I removed

```
#include "cuda.h"
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
```

from the .cuh file.  And added this to the cmake file

```
find_package(Maya REQUIRED)
find_package(CUDA REQUIRED)

enable_language(CUDA)
set(CMAKE_CUDA_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CUDA_FLAGS} -gencode arch=compute_50,code=sm_50 -lcuda -lcudart")

include_directories(${MAYA_INCLUDE_DIR} ${CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${MAYA_LIBRARY_DIR} ${CUDA_LIBS})
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${MAYA_LIBRARIES} ${CUDA_LIBRARIES})
```